# mysql join not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 database tables that looks like this

**Subscriptions table**

```
member_id    active
5            1 
7            0
8            1
```

**Plans Table**

```
member_id    disk
5            2000
7            5000
8            3000
```

Ii want to show `disk` for the currently logged in user where active = 1. So if currently logged in user is has member_id 8 and his `active = 1` we will show 3000. We get the currently logged in user by doing `$this->EE->session->userdata('member_id')`

I have the following SELECT statement, but it's not working. it's throwing `500 internal server error`. do you see anything wrong with it.

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT disk FROM exp_membrr_plans p JOIN exp_membrr_subscriptions s ON p.member_id = s.member_id WHERE p.member_id = $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id') AND s.active=1 LIMIT 1");
$results->row('p.disk'); // the problem seems to be here. If i comment out this line i get no error
```

Comment: Try $results = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT disk FROM exp_membrr_plans p JOIN exp_membrr_subscriptions s ON p.member_id = s.member_id WHERE p.member_id = " . $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id') . " AND s.active=1 LIMIT 1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it into something like this:

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT disk FROM exp_membrr_plans p JOIN exp_membrr_subscriptions s ON p.member_id = s.member_id WHERE p.member_id = " . $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id') . " AND s.active=1 LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: That still doesn't work and throws a 500 error. If i do a simple select statement without join then it works.

Comment: can you see your server log, and write down the exact error message? 500 is Internal Server Error.

Comment: Looking into this further i see the error is with what comes after it `$results->row('p.disk');`. Does this look correct to you.

Comment: can you change it to: `$results->row('disk');`. Btw, what is the exact error message?

Comment: I tried that, no luck. i will check the error log and let you know

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. Changing p.disk to disk as you suggested solved the issue. I just had to refresh the browser multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's parser is kind of stupid and not "greedy". You're embedding a multi-level object call inside a string, which in PHP is a no-no:

```
... p.member_id = $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id') AND ...
```

PHP's parser will see that as `$this->EE` as an object call, followed by some plain text `->session->userdata(..)`.

To force the whole call hierarchy to be parsed as a single unit, you have to surround it with `{}`:

```
... p.member_id = {$this->EE->session->userdata('member_id')} AND ...
```

Comment: This is still not working. Looking into this further, I believe the issue is with what comes after it `$x = $results->row('p.disk');`. if i comment this code out, then i get not error. Am i doing it correctly by having `$results->row('p.disk')`

Comment: Thanks for the curly braces suggestion. +1